# Add CSS content image after <input> element

Tags: html, css, forms, class, input

I cannot reach to add an image after an input element for form validation with JQuery. Doesn't work also if I add the class manually on the element...

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#last_name').addClass('cross');
      });
</script>

<label for="last_name">*Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="last_name" value="<?=$last_name?>" />
```

CSS:

```
.cross:after {
    content:url(/ico/cross.png);
    /* Tried also with:
      content:url('/ico/cross.png');
    AND
      content: '';
      background:url(/ico/no_check.png); */
}
```

Comment: The `::after` pseudo-element places the 'element' *within* the element itself 'after' its contents (not after the element), an `input` is a void element that cannot contain any other HTML. This cannot work, unfortunately. See, for example: "CSS :after pseudo element on INPUT field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)."

Comment: Thank you, can I reach that with jQuery .after? Is it possible to add an image inside .after()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `::after` pseudo-element places the 'element' *within* the element itself 'after' its contents (not after the element), an `input` is a void element that cannot contain any other HTML. This cannot work, unfortunately. See, for example: "[CSS :after pseudo element on INPUT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)."

With jQuery, however, you could *add* a new image (not a background-image, or pseudo-element) using the following (though untested):

```
$('.cross').after('<img src="ico/cross.png" />');
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qugeX/).

References:

- [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Comment: What I thought, see comment! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you would do better using this route:

## [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/oHAyASu/1/edit)

### CSS:

```
label[for='last_name'] {
  content: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png);
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

**And to distinguish it in writing, use `placeholder`:**

```
<label for="last_name"></label>
<input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" />
```