# Set input-suffix for certain input fields with CSS

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am working on an input form, with different *input fields*. They all get an attribute with their `form`.

Eg:

```
<input class="input-text" form="price">
```

or

```
<input class="input-text" form="percent">
```

I would like to add a suffix with the pseudo element `::after` but cannot figure out how.

Ive already tried this **CSS**:

```
input[form="price"]::after{
    content: "&euro;";
}
```

and this:

```
input::after[form="price"]{
    content: "&euro;";
}
```

The problem seems to be with the `::after` itself, but i cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: In addition to the answers given about generated content on input elements, there are a couple of other issues with your attempts 1) `content` being a CSS property does not understand HTML character entity references - you can either use the appropriate Unicode escape or the actual euro symbol 2) `::after` being a pseudo-element must be placed last in the selector.

Comment: Agree. You have to use `€` instead of `&euro;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo classes like `after` and `before` cannot work on input elements. Why so? 
Because they work only on elements which can contain html markup. An input tag doesn't.

[Robert Koritnik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/2600397) explained this [quite good in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field).

There're other questions like that and like this:

- [CSS :after input does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840768/css-after-input-does-not-seem-to-work)
- [Add CSS content image after input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20894255/add-css-content-image-after-input-element)

Answer (score 1):

Clearly saying no you cannot do that in non container tags.

According to w3 standard `:after` or `:before` can be used in only container element.
So you will have to use javascript.

See specification http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content

But there is an alternative you can use `contenteditable` property which makes div editable & then you can use after tag. But `contenteditable` is introduced in html5.

Here is a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/madterry/W4Y58/ . Down side is you cannot use this as form field & it is not widely supported.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that pseude elements are only **supported** on **container elements**, but not on allready replaced elements like *images* or input *fields*.

This is because they get rendered in the element **itself**, which is clearly impossible on *input* elements.

In the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content) it is even defined.